# Countdown is unexpected decreasing select-elements value by one once and do not go further after that

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding a countdown. The time is selectable, when you clicking start after you selected your time the countdown is starting. Unfortunately, when my countdown is started the countdown value is decreased by one once and after that my countdown is not working further. I do not no why, what is my failure?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const starter = document.getElementById("actioner");
  const reseter = document.getElementById("reseter");

  const sp = document.querySelector("span");
  const minutesFromSelector = document.getElementById("selM");
  const secondsFromSelector = document.getElementById("selS");

  let interval = null;

  addEventListener("change", () => {
    sp.innerHTML =
      minutesFromSelector.value + ":" + secondsFromSelector.value;
  });

  reseter.addEventListener("click", () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
    sp.innerHTML = "00 : 00";
    minutesFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
    secondsFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
    starter.innerText = "Start";
  });

  starter.addEventListener("click", () => {
    starter.innerText = "Stop";
    if (!interval) {
      interval = setInterval(regulSec, 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = null;
      starter.innerText = "Resume"
    }
  });

  function regulSec() {
    minutes = minutesFromSelector.value;
    seconds = secondsFromSelector.value;
    if (seconds == 0) {
      minutes--;
      seconds = 59;
    } else {
      seconds--;
    }
    sec = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    min = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    sp.innerHTML = ` ${min} : ${sec} `;
    if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffff;
}
```

```html
<span>00:00</span>
<button id="actioner">Start</button>
<button id="reseter">reset</button>
<select id="selM">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
  <option>13</option>
  <option>14</option>
  <option>15</option>
  <option>16</option>
  <option>17</option>
  <option>18</option>
  <option>19</option>
  <option>20</option>
  <option>21</option>
  <option>22</option>
  <option>23</option>
  <option>24</option>
  <option>25</option>
  <option>26</option>
  <option>27</option>
  <option>28</option>
  <option>29</option>
  <option>30</option>
  <option>31</option>
  <option>32</option>
  <option>33</option>
  <option>34</option>
  <option>35</option>
  <option>36</option>
  <option>37</option>
  <option>38</option>
  <option>39</option>
  <option>40</option>
  <option>41</option>
  <option>42</option>
  <option>43</option>
  <option>44</option>
  <option>45</option>
  <option>46</option>
  <option>47</option>
  <option>48</option>
  <option>49</option>
  <option>50</option>
  <option>51</option>
  <option>52</option>
  <option>53</option>
  <option>54</option>
  <option>55</option>
  <option>56</option>
  <option>57</option>
  <option>58</option>
  <option>59</option>
</select>

<select id="selS">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
  <option>13</option>
  <option>14</option>
  <option>15</option>
  <option>16</option>
  <option>17</option>
  <option>18</option>
  <option>19</option>
  <option>20</option>
  <option>21</option>
  <option>22</option>
  <option>23</option>
  <option>24</option>
  <option>25</option>
  <option>26</option>
  <option>27</option>
  <option>28</option>
  <option>29</option>
  <option>30</option>
  <option>31</option>
  <option>32</option>
  <option>33</option>
  <option>34</option>
  <option>35</option>
  <option>36</option>
  <option>37</option>
  <option>38</option>
  <option>39</option>
  <option>40</option>
  <option>41</option>
  <option>42</option>
  <option>43</option>
  <option>44</option>
  <option>45</option>
  <option>46</option>
  <option>47</option>
  <option>48</option>
  <option>49</option>
  <option>50</option>
  <option>51</option>
  <option>52</option>
  <option>53</option>
  <option>54</option>
  <option>55</option>
  <option>56</option>
  <option>57</option>
  <option>58</option>
  <option>59</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function that is run with the timer, you are getting the value of the drop down for minutes and seconds. Which means every time it is ran, you are getting the same information.

I declared seconds and minutes outside of the function and moved them to the
starter event handler since you only need to get them on START.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const starter = document.getElementById("actioner");
  const reseter = document.getElementById("reseter");
  let seconds = 0;
  let minutes = 0;
  const sp = document.querySelector("span");
  const minutesFromSelector = document.getElementById("selM");
  const secondsFromSelector = document.getElementById("selS");

  let interval = null;

  addEventListener("change", () => {
    sp.innerHTML =
      minutesFromSelector.value + ":" + secondsFromSelector.value;
  });

  reseter.addEventListener("click", () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
    sp.innerHTML = "00 : 00";
    minutesFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
    secondsFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
    starter.innerText = "Start";
  });

  starter.addEventListener("click", () => {
    starter.innerText = "Stop";
    if (!interval) {
    minutes = minutesFromSelector.value;
    seconds = secondsFromSelector.value;
      interval = setInterval(regulSec, 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = null;
      starter.innerText = "Resume"
    }
  });

  function regulSec() {
    if (seconds == 0) {
      minutes--;
      seconds = 59;
    } else {
      seconds--;
    }
    sec = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    min = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    sp.innerHTML = ` ${min} : ${sec} `;
    if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffff;
}
```

```html
<span>00:00</span>
<button id="actioner">Start</button>
<button id="reseter">reset</button>
<select id="selM">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
  <option>13</option>
  <option>14</option>
  <option>15</option>
  <option>16</option>
  <option>17</option>
  <option>18</option>
  <option>19</option>
  <option>20</option>
  <option>21</option>
  <option>22</option>
  <option>23</option>
  <option>24</option>
  <option>25</option>
  <option>26</option>
  <option>27</option>
  <option>28</option>
  <option>29</option>
  <option>30</option>
  <option>31</option>
  <option>32</option>
  <option>33</option>
  <option>34</option>
  <option>35</option>
  <option>36</option>
  <option>37</option>
  <option>38</option>
  <option>39</option>
  <option>40</option>
  <option>41</option>
  <option>42</option>
  <option>43</option>
  <option>44</option>
  <option>45</option>
  <option>46</option>
  <option>47</option>
  <option>48</option>
  <option>49</option>
  <option>50</option>
  <option>51</option>
  <option>52</option>
  <option>53</option>
  <option>54</option>
  <option>55</option>
  <option>56</option>
  <option>57</option>
  <option>58</option>
  <option>59</option>
</select>

<select id="selS">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
  <option>13</option>
  <option>14</option>
  <option>15</option>
  <option>16</option>
  <option>17</option>
  <option>18</option>
  <option>19</option>
  <option>20</option>
  <option>21</option>
  <option>22</option>
  <option>23</option>
  <option>24</option>
  <option>25</option>
  <option>26</option>
  <option>27</option>
  <option>28</option>
  <option>29</option>
  <option>30</option>
  <option>31</option>
  <option>32</option>
  <option>33</option>
  <option>34</option>
  <option>35</option>
  <option>36</option>
  <option>37</option>
  <option>38</option>
  <option>39</option>
  <option>40</option>
  <option>41</option>
  <option>42</option>
  <option>43</option>
  <option>44</option>
  <option>45</option>
  <option>46</option>
  <option>47</option>
  <option>48</option>
  <option>49</option>
  <option>50</option>
  <option>51</option>
  <option>52</option>
  <option>53</option>
  <option>54</option>
  <option>55</option>
  <option>56</option>
  <option>57</option>
  <option>58</option>
  <option>59</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you. I want to ask if it is recommended to declare variables always outside from functions

Comment: @madara030 when declaring variables, SCOPE is the most important thing to take into consideration. If the variables are only used within the function AND the variable doesn't need to change every time that function is used (ie increment) then you should declare it inside of the function. However, if the variable is used elsewhere or like in your case the variable will be changed every time the function is ran, then you will need to declare it outside of the function.